# Encryption and decryption with same length of characters in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, encryption, sql-server-2014

I want to encrypt string with the same length of character string and decryption with same length of character string using sql server. For Example:

```
Encryption
Input: Encrypt("002581") -- with 6 characters

Result: a&pE12 -- output with same 6 characters in encrypted form

Decryption
Input: Decrypt("a&pE12") -- with 6 characters
Result: 002581 -- output with same 6 characters in decrypted form
```

Comment: Even if there were a way to do this, your requirement might limit which encryption algorithms are available.  Also, if a malicious person caught on to this, he would already know the length of the actual unencrypted password.  Maybe you can tell us why you think you need this.

Comment: Basically I want to validate the record with it's entry code with the same length of characters. That's why i required that kind of encryption and decryption using sql server technique.

Comment: When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead  use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with about a 100ms duration. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score -1):

**Short answer**: there is no such *secure* encryption scheme.

**Longer answer**: any kind of encryption scheme obfuscates content of a plain text to be indistinguishable from other messages from the same message space. To do so all cipher texts produced must be of the same length (ideally) regardless of an input plain text. At least the length should be different from a length of a plain text.

So please, don't even consider such an encryption technique. It's insecure by definition.